# Minimalist alternative to Rhythmbox

Tags: sound, software-recommendation, rhythmbox, music, default-programs

Is there a good music player for 12.04 that is simple, text-based, and lightweight? I would like something that doesn't use up much CPU, and looks clean, with little GUI.

I've seen a simple, terminal-like one for arch, but I was wondering if such thing exists for Ubuntu.

Comment: Look at cmus, for example. In general, you just need to look it up on Google (because there are lots of options). Cmus is CLI-based, you can also try with GMusicBrowser (its shimmer interface looks nice).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`text-based`

I used to use `cmus`, but it had some trouble handling tags. I used an old version of it, though:

[image]

I currently use `moc` and love it. It's highly customizeable:

[image]

There's also `ncmpcpp`. It is also highly customizeable:

[image]

Comment: It would be nice if you included links to the source of the software.